# moment.js returning invaild date for every entry except the first when used on a angular 1.5 filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

So I decided to make a simple moment filter for formatting my times however I have an issue where the first input from a `ng-repeat` list will go through it correct but all the rest return invaild, yet when i manually enter the same line in through the console with the same input I get a correct output.
Here's the input

```
App.filter('momentFilter', function () {
    return function (dateString, format, isUtc) {
        console.log(dateString);
        if (isUtc) {
            var result = moment.utc(dateString).local().format(format);
            console.log(result );
            return result;
        }
        var result = moment(dateString).format(format);
        console.log(result );
        return result ;
    };
});
```

my ng-repeat loop

```
<div ng-repeat="rank in rankings">
    <div flex="15">
        <label>Start Time: </label> {{rank.startTime | momentFilter:'D-MM':true}}
    </div>
</div>
```

and a picture of the data/result with my manual input of the second item at the bottom showing that it's correct

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send `dateString` like `1460028524737` as a string then you should convert it `string` to `integer` first. then will be working fine.

```
var dateValue = parseInt(dateString);
var result = moment.utc(dateValue).local().format(format);
```

and you should use else in your function otherwise always execute `moment(dateString).format(format)` and get that result, or use before `if (isUtc)` condition

```
return function (dateString, format, isUtc) {
    console.log(dateString);
    var dateValue = parseInt(dateString);
    if (isUtc) {
       var result = moment.utc(dateValue).local().format(format);
       console.log(result );
       return result;
    } else {
       var result = moment(dateValue).format(format);
       console.log(result );
       return result ;
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry, minor typo when try it before, yep it appears to be working